# Why Angular doesn't detect changes when used to develop chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple bookmarks chrome extension and using Angular as a framework, probably not the best choice for such tasks, but I wanted to try it out.

Following this article [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575) it all seems logical. However, I started running into very strange problems.

When I click on the bookmark Icon, the bookmark view inputs are not populated with values from chrome API (seems that Angular doesn't fire up change detection or something like this, I'm new to front-end and Angular in general). In order for the view to change I need to click on one of the inputs then click on another input after that the view changes.

Another observation is when I use `<select>` input when I select an option the input doesn't change I need to click on one of the text inputs in order to see the change. I believe the inputs must be filled up as the code `chrome.tabs.query` is executed in the component's constructor. I suspect that this code runs outside of Angular hence angular don't fire change detection so I tried `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and it worked for updating inputs when I click on bookmark icon but this didn't solve the issue `<select>` so the problem might be even deeper.

Here is the components code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-bookmark',
    templateUrl: './add-bookmark.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-bookmark.component.css']
})
export class AddBookmarkComponent implements OnInit {


    url: string = "";
    directory: string = "";
    description: string = "";
    tags: string[] = [];
    image: string;
    recentFolders = [];
    folderId: string = "2";

    constructor() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
            let activeTab = tabs[0];
            this.url = activeTab.url;
            this.description = activeTab.title;
            this.image = activeTab.favIconUrl;
           // ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); //this worked and inputs are updated but It didn't solve the issue with Select. 
        });

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container align-items-center p-2">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="mb-1">
                <img *ngIf="image" [src]="image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-1">
                <label for="url" class="form-label">URL</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control form-control-sm" id="url"
                       aria-describedby="url" [(ngModel)]="url" name="url">

            </div>
            <div class="m-1">
                <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="description" aria-describedby="desc"
                          [(ngModel)]="description" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="m-1">
                <label for="description" class="form-label">Select Folder:</label>
                <select id="selected_dirs" class="form-select form-control form-control-sm"
                        aria-label="Default select example"
                        name="directory">
                    <option *ngFor="let f1 of recentFolders" [ngValue]="f1.id">{{f1.name}}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 mb-2">

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="openManager()">Open Manager</button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-2" (click)="addBookmark()">Add bookmark</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a visual demo

It is supposed to fill URL and Description

[image]

Click on an input field, nothing happens

[image]

Click on another input field and it works

[image]

Here is the "inspect" window from the bookmark.
[image]

Thanks for taking some time to read this long question.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. In devtools you can check for errors in console and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is, the issue is the angular detection. It works like that whenever there is any change in the data in the component angular runs change detection to render this change on the view. There can be two strategy OnPush or default. You can enable it like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-bookmark',
    templateUrl: './add-bookmark.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-bookmark.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. //you can change it to default ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

In this case(default) whenever your data changes in the component, angular runs this by itself. But it makes the things little laggy, you check it if that works for you.

So, My suggestion is whenever you make any change in the view, you need to run the change detection to update the view. To do that, add a Hostlistener and whenever user clicks on this component you can fire change detection.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core'; // add in component file
```

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onMouseEnter(event: any) {    
      
  //Run change detection.
  this.changeDetection();
}

public changeDetection() { 
   this.ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

This listener will be restricted to this component only. If you want to get more details about change detection: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Also, If there is any context issue that you face while debug you can use Ngzone: https://angular.io/guide/zone